# How can i implement weather map as Weather Channel App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, dictionary, xcode4

I am implementing [HAMweather's Aeris API](http://www.hamweather.com/products/aeris-api/) for weather map radar. It is not showing weather like in the weather channel app. It is giving me result in console

```
  2013-03-11 11:54:58.298 C2S[1487:c07] [AerisEngine] Account does not have access to tile overlay for code {radar}.
  2013-03-11 11:54:59.666 C2S[1487:c07] [AerisEngine] API response received, used cache: NO
```

Can anybody help me?

Weather channel app showing weather like shown in this pic:
[image: Weather channel app showing weather]

Aeris is giving me this map only:
[image: Aeris is giving me this map]

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems you're describing here.

1 )

You apparently don't have the correct access to display data (the "Account does not have access to tile overlay for code" error).

2 )

[Aeris / HAMweather is not the same thing as the Weather Channel](http://www.hamweather.com/support/documentation/mobile/ios/starting/)

3 )

[Weather Channel has their own API](http://press.weather.com/press-releases/the-weather-channel-launches-new-api-for-developers/).  It's "as low as $20 per month" to access.  I didn't get far enough in my research to discover if they have an iOS api.  Can you afford the $20 per month?

Comment: yes Michael Dautermaan  i have created Aris api's free key i think it would not provide me full access of this functionality so that it give me that error.yes i know about aris is not same as Weather Channel.but can you provide right way to implement it without any cost

Comment: [Another option is to try to make use of Weather Underground's API's](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/). It is free to get started, but it looks like the one thing all of these API's have in common is that you have to pay *something* in order to make use of them in production apps. To me, a monthly charge of $20 is reasonable (for the amount of engineering and effort that goes into supplying the data that goes into these maps). Is it reasonable to you? That's the only way you're going to get a map that reasonably approximates the Weather Channel's.

Comment: michael how can i implement it in iPhone..can i put this url in Web view or other  ...http://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/?sat=1 i got this url